# Test of concavity for repeated measures data

Tags: repeated-measures, quadratic-form, concavity

First question here. I'm trying to figure out what statistical test is appropriate for testing whether a series of data is concave or convex. Specifically, this is coming from a human subjects experiment where individuals rate a stimulus on 9 occasions (so I have 9 observations per respondent over time). I'd like to know if the shape of their average ratings is concave or convex. The image below is the average ratings for all respondents across the 9 iterations. I can test whether the shape is best fit by a line or a quadric function (using contrasts in repeated measures ANOVA), but I'm not sure how to test if the quadric contrast is concave or convex...at least not statistically speaking.

I used SPSS for this, but I'm reasonably proficient in STATA and R if SPSS isn't up to this.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Your *data* (as can be seen from the plot) are neither concave nor convex. You are presumably interested in testing something about the population, under some set of assumptions. Since there's also a third possibility (that the population is also neither concave nor convex) and indeed a fourth possibility (that it is actually both, since linear functions would count in either category) you'll need to be more explicit about your specific null or nulls and your specific alternatives as well as your assumptions. You mention a quadratic model; if you *assume* that it's quadratic, ... ctd

Comment: ctd then testing convexity vs concavity boils down to a test of the sign of the coefficient of $x^2$ (but your data don't look consistent with being quadratic).  What are these ratings? How are they obtained? Why does it make sense to average across subjects? What is this x-variable measuring? (its scale matters; a simple transformation could move you from convexity to concavity, so your conclusions apply only to whatever scale this variable is measured on). [And if it's an ordinal scale it doesn't make sense to talk about convexity or concavity]